# Newtonsoft.Json mismatch in FacebookWebMVC NuGet package?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

After loading the Facebook C# SDK (FacebookWebMVC) library from NuGet, I followed exactly the steps at this (excellent!) walkthrough [Getting Started with an ASP.NET MVC 3 Website](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website&referringTitle=Getting%20Started).

I've got my own FB key/secret, implemented the 3 classes in the tutorial, but have this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
>   ....
>
> WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number

Occurs on this line:

```
var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(new Dictionary<string, object> 
               { { "state", returnUrl } });
```

Note the 4.0.0.0. Rather on disk is 4.0.2.0; this came bundled in the NuGet package. This file is copied, as expected to my project's `bin` dir. Version 4.0.2.13622

`d:\myproj\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.4.0.2\lib\net40-full\Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download release 1 instead of release 2 of the [Newtonsoft.Json](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/58535).

Comment: I'd (naively?) assumed a NuGet package would've included the correct dependency!

Comment: Apparently not, because you need to specify the reference in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem today as well.  I removed the NuGet packages entirely, used a copy of Newtonsoft.Json.WindowsPhone.dll that I downloaded from the NewtonSoft.Json download page, and I'm using a copy of Facebook.dll that I built here.  I don't think you need to build Facebook.dll, it was just that I did that during the course of trying to get somewhere with this problem today.